# Is there a way to simple Haskell class instance?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I define a `Pixel` data with different size like this.

```
data Pixel = RGB8 Word8 Word8 Word8
           | RGBA8 Word8 Word8 Word8 Word8
           | RGB16 Word16 Word16 Word16
           | RGBA16 Word16 Word16 Word16 Word16
           | Empty
           deriving (Eq)
```

and `Num` instance

```
instance Num Pixel where
  x + Empty = x
  Empty + x = x
  (RGB8 ru gu bu) + (RGB8 rv gv bv) = RGB8 (ru + rv) (gu + gv) (bu + bv)
  (RGBA8 ru gu bu au) + (RGBA8 rv gv bv av) = RGBA8 (ru + rv) (gu + gv) (bu + bv) (au + av)
  (RGB16 ru gu bu) + (RGB16 rv gv bv) = RGB16 (ru + rv) (gu + gv) (bu + bv)
  (RGBA16 ru gu bu au) + (RGBA16 rv gv bv av) = RGBA16 (ru + rv) (gu + gv) (bu + bv) (au + av)
  x - Empty = x
  Empty - x = x
  (RGB8 ru gu bu) - (RGB8 rv gv bv) = RGB8 (ru - rv) (gu - gv) (bu - bv)
  (RGB16 ru gu bu) - (RGB16 rv gv bv) = RGB16 (ru - rv) (gu - gv) (bu - bv)
  (RGBA8 ru gu bu au) - (RGBA8 rv gv bv av) = RGBA8 (ru - rv) (gu - gv) (bu - bv) (au - av)
  (RGBA16 ru gu bu au) - (RGBA16 rv gv bv av) = RGBA16 (ru - rv) (gu - gv) (bu - bv) (au - av)
  _ * _ = error "Not support multiply"
  abs  = id
  signum _ = error "Not support signum"
  fromInteger _ = error "Not support fromInteger"
```

It's very ugly and bored. I think Haskell is a Elegant language, so can I have a better style to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above all, such an instance doesn't make any sense. A composite entity can't have much in common with a number, which the fact that your instance consists of just partial and undefined functions is only the evidence of.

---

With regards to your concern about the verbosity of the instance declaration, it was caused by you choosing an incorrect approach to type declaration.

Pixels of different bit-depths are appropriately described as different types, and not different constructors of the same type. The analogy is right before you: `Word8` and `Word16` are different types, not constructors.

Taking the said above into account I recommend you to reapproach your problem the following way:

```
-- The separate datatypes. Note the absense of `Empty` constructors, as there
-- is no such thing as empty pixel. There are black and transparent pixels,
-- which should be described as `PixelRGB8 0 0 0` or `PixelRGBA8 0 0 0 0`,
-- but not empty. And for dealing with missing pixels we have a `Maybe` type.
data PixelRGB8 = PixelRGB8 Word8 Word8 Word8
-- ...
data PixelRGBA16 = PixelRGBA16 Word16 Word16 Word16 Word16

-- We're taking an analogous approach to Num/Integral typeclasses, while 
-- combining both the "to" and "from" functionality in a single typeclass.
class Pixel a where
  -- whether its toPixelRGBA16 or possibly toRGBA64Pixel should depend on
  -- the highest precision type you want to be dealing with
  toPixelRGBA16 :: a -> PixelRGBA16
  fromPixelRGBA16 :: PixelRGBA16 -> a
  -- And here's addition for pixels of same type:
  addPixel :: a -> a -> a

instance Pixel PixelRGB8 where
  toPixelRGBA16 = error "TODO"
  fromPixelRGBA16 = error "TODO"
  addPixel = error "TODO"

instance Pixel PixelRGBA16 where
  toPixelRGBA16 = id
  fromPixelRGBA16 = id
  addPixel = error "TODO"

-- Here's addition for pixels of differing types:
addArbitraryPixel :: (Pixel a, Pixel b) => a -> b -> PixelRGBA16
addArbitraryPixel a b = addPixel (toPixelRGBA16 a) (toPixelRGBA16 b)
```

Comment: But I need pixel addition and pixel has different data type (8-bit, 16-bit). Do you have any idea to define a pixel? Thanks for answer

Comment: @Pikaurd Volkov's right.

As for what you should do, check the `Vector a` type from the following link:
http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses

The article is a good introduction to the subject.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca Thanks your link. I'll try to rewrite it.

Comment: @Pikaurd See the updates to the answer

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers saying that you should have different types for your different pixels.

That said, you can probably define a single polymorphic type and write a lot less code:

```
data Pixel a n = Pixel (a n) n n n

data NoAlpha n = NoAlpha

newtype Alpha n = Alpha n

type PixelRGB8 = Pixel NoAlpha Word8

type PixelRGBA8 = Pixel Alpha Word8

type PixelRGB16 = Pixel NoAlpha Word16

type PixelRGBA16 = Pixel Alpha Word16
```

Then, you can define pixel addition once for all the types (with a little helper for the alpha types):

```
class AddAlpha a where
  addAlpha :: (Num n) => a n -> a n -> a n

instance AddAlpha NoAlpha where
  addAlpha _ _ = NoAlpha

instance AddAlpha Alpha where
  addAlpha (Alpha a) (Alpha b) = Alpha (a + b)

addPixels :: (Num n, AddAlpha a) => Pixel a n -> Pixel a n -> Pixel a n
-- I'll leave the definition up to you.
```